# Using REF inside an INCLUDEPICTURE field?

Tags: ms-word, fieldcodes

I've been tasked with generating QR Codes for some documents (Word 2010) using values already filled in by users in some form fields.

I've set up an ASK field in the document that collects a number.

I then tried to "concatenate" that value into a URL that queries the Google Charts API.

This is the content of the INCLUDEPICTURE field: `INCLUDEPICTURE  "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=120x120&chl=2011-AEX-{REF NumCaso}" \* MERGEFORMAT`

The problem is that the QR Code seems to be generated with the string as-is: "2011-AEX-{REF NumCaso}" (the REF value is not replaced).

Is there any way I can accomplish that with a reference to the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me exactly the way you have it...

1. Are you sure that the { REF } subfield is a proper field? Subfields may look like ordinary curlies, but they're not. If you typed in the {}'s by hand or cut/pasted from somewhere, delete your {REF...} and insert a new subfield marker with Ctrl-F9, then type in the " REF NumCaso " inside the curlies. Notice the spaces.
2. You need to have one space between the { and the REF, and also one between NumCaso and }. I can't tell if you just forgot to copy them when posting here, but you do need them.

Comment: MilesK, you first observation was right. I copied the "code" for the INCLUDEPICTURE from an example online, changing it to a REF instead of a MERGEFIELD, apparently screwing it up in the process. As for the second point, I initialy had the space, then removed it, then tried lowercase, then camelcase, and ended up pasting a messed-up version. Thanks!